# Форма отправки на почту

Tags: php, html, html-form

Добрый день. Не могли бы вы помочь мне объединить мою форму, с рабочим вариантом?
Вот моя форма:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css"/>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 forma">
     <form>
      <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 name" name='nameFF' id="nameFF" x-autocompletetype="name"placeholder='Имя *'/>
      <input type="text" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 Email" name='Email' placeholder='Email *'/>
      <input type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Subject" name='Subject' placeholder='Тема'/>
      <textarea type="text" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 Message" name='Message' placeholder='Сообщение *'></textarea>
      <div class="cBtn col-xs-12">
       <ul>
        <li class="clear"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Очистить</a></li>
        <li class="clear"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>Добавить фото</a></li>
        <li class="send"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>Заказать работу</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Нужно с вот этим рабочим вариантом:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="feedback-form">
<label for="nameFF">Имя:</label>
<input type="text" name="nameFF" id="nameFF" required placeholder="например, Иван Иванович Иванов" x-autocompletetype="name" class="w100 border">
<label for="contactFF">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="contactFF" id="contactFF" required placeholder="например, ivan@yandex.ru" x-autocompletetype="email" class="w100 border">
<label for="fileFF">Прикрепить файл:</label>
<input type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" class="w100">
<label for="messageFF">Сообщение:</label>
<textarea name="messageFF" id="messageFF" required rows="5" placeholder="Детали заявки…" class="w100 border"></textarea>
<br>
<input value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF">
</form>
```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду объеденить?

Comment: Выполнять работу за вас никто не станет. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись. Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы - спрашивайте